# Query SolR for uniq value in multiple field

Tags: solr, solr-query-syntax

i'm looking for a particular SolR query that can select a value in a field, only if it is unique.

for exemple, here is some documents :

```xml
<doc>
  <id>1</id>
  <folder_id>abc;def;ghi</folder_id>
</doc>

<doc>
  <id>2</id>
  <folder_id>def</folder_id>
</doc>
```

If I ask solr for the `folder_id:"def"`, it will gives me back the two documents, but I want only the one with `id: 2`

What I want is to be able to retrieve all the documents that have the key `def` and only this one.
Unfortunatly I can't be able to retreive all the other keys to be able to create a query like this one `folder_id:"def" AND NOT folder_id:("abc", "ghi")`

[image]

Let me know if you guys need some more info

Comment: apply the string field type to your field folder_id  and reindex the data...String type would bring the exact match for you and get only one document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `String` as field type for your field instead of text.

`String` stores a word/sentence as an exact string without performing tokenization etc. Commonly useful for storing exact matches, e.g, for facetting. `Text` typically performs tokenization, and secondary processing (such as lower-casing etc.).

Currently you have field type as `Text` and it is tokenizing the text and creating separate tokens. Hence you are getting 2 results.

If you apply the String type to your field then you will be able to achieve the exact match.

You can also have the `KeywordTokenizer` with `lowercasefilter` factory for your field.

If you want tokenization then you can have 2 fields, one with String type and other with Text type. It all depends on your requirement.